# Disable horizontal scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using [jquery-mousewheel](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel) to make the site scroll horizontal when I am scrolling up and down on the mousepad.

This is the code for that:

```
var $ = require('jquery-browserify');
require('jquery-mousewheel')($);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 2);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

I want to disable the ability to use horizontal scrolling on the mousepad to scroll horizontal on the page (i.e. that only the up and down scroll event will trigger the horizontal scrolling).

How can I do that?

Comment: like this http://jsbin.com/zunuxut/2/edit?js,output?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MariusBalaj. In that code, I can still scroll horizontal by scrolling horizontal on my mousepad. I only want the site to scroll horizontal by scrolling up and down on my mousepad. It's a little tricky to explain, but do you get it?